# Tokenize a sentence where each word contains only letters using RegexTokenizer Scala

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark, tokenize

I am using spark with scala and trying to tokenize a sentence where each word should only contain letters. Here is my code

```
def tokenization(extractedText: String): DataFrame = {

    val existingSparkSession = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val textDataFrame = existingSparkSession.createDataFrame(Seq(
      (0, extractedText))).toDF("id", "sentence")
    val tokenizer = new Tokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words")
    val regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer()
      .setInputCol("sentence")
      .setOutputCol("words")
      .setPattern("\\W")
    val regexTokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(textDataFrame)
    regexTokenized.select("sentence", "words").show(false)
    return regexTokenized;
  }
```

If I provide senetence as "I am going to school5" after tokenization it should have only [i, am, going, to] and should drop school5. But with my current pattern it doesn't ignore the digits within words. How am I suppose to drop words with digits ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the settings below to get your desired tokenization. Essentially you extract words which only contain letters using an appropriate regex pattern.

```
val regexTokenizer = new RegexTokenizer().setInputCol("sentence").setOutputCol("words").setGaps(false).setPattern("\\b[a-zA-Z]+\\b")

val regexTokenized = regexTokenizer.transform(textDataFrame)

regexTokenized.show(false)
+---+---------------------+------------------+
|id |sentence             |words             |
+---+---------------------+------------------+
|0  |I am going to school5|[i, am, going, to]|
+---+---------------------+------------------+
```

For the reason why I set `gaps` to `false`, see the docs:

> A regex based tokenizer that extracts tokens either by using the provided regex pattern (in Java dialect) to split the text (default) or **repeatedly matching the regex (if gaps is false)**. Optional parameters also allow filtering tokens using a minimal length. It returns an array of strings that can be empty.

You want to repeatedly match the regex, rather than splitting the text by a given regex.